# Why <T extends { [K in keyof T]?: string } = {}>? Why not use <T> directly?

Tags: typescript

Why `<T extends { [K in keyof T]?: string } = {}>`? Why not use `<T>` directly?

```
    function useQuery<T extends { [K in keyof T]?: string } = {}>(): { [K in keyof T]?: string } {
      const location = useLocation()
      const searchStr = location.search.split('?')[1]
      // 参数对象
      let params: any = {}
      if (searchStr) {
        const searchArr = searchStr.split('&')
        searchArr.forEach((item) => {
          let key = item.split('=')[0]
          let value = item.split('=')[1]
          if (key && value) {
            params[key] = value
          }
        })
      }
      const [query] = useState<{ [K in keyof T]?: string }>(params)
    
      return query
    }
    
    const { id } = useQuery<{ id: string }>()
```

[image: code image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sure the value of each key in type `T` is `string`.

For example, if `T` is `{ a: 1 }`, the constraint will be mapped to `{ a?: string }`. Since `{ a: 1 }` is not a subtype of `{ a?: string }`, the compiler rejects it.

On the other hand, if `T` is `{ b: 'some literal' }`, the constraint will be mapped to `{ b?: string }`. Since `{ b: 'some literal' }` is a subtype of `{ b?: string }`, the compiler accepts it.

Comment: So the use of T extends { [K in keyof T]?: string } = {} is to satisfy that the attribute value in generic t is string?

Comment: Then {[K in key of T]?: String} = {} is it unnecessary to set the default value?

Comment: (1) Yes, it makes sure the type of each field is a `string` and it is optional (maybe `undefined`). (2) I have tested it in the typescript playground and it seems to be unnecessary as typescript can infer `T` from context.

Comment: Can we change it to useState<{ [K in keyof T]?: string }>(params) in useState<T>(params)?

Comment: You cannot change it because the mapped type add `?` to each key making each field to be optional.